# What is this define declaration?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I saw this code in an application but I don't recognize the syntax. I have to make an equivalent in C++ but this code is in C.

How can make this run in a C++ application? What's the name of this kind of define? This is the same that define every constant on the list?

```
/*! Object types */
#define F_ENUM(x, y) x = y,
#define F_SWITCH(x, y) case x: return ( #x );

#define OB_LIST(f) \
  f(T0, 0) \   //this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
               //identifier "T0" is undefined 
  f(T1, 1) \   //expected a ")"
               //unrecognized token  
               //expected a ";"
  f(T2, 2) \
  f(T3, 3) \
  f(T4, 4) \
  f(T5, 5)

enum mxt_object_type {
  OB_LIST(F_ENUM)
};
```

Moreover when I compile this in a C++ complier, I get errors like this:

```
this declaration has no storage class or type specifier 
identifier "T0" is undefined 
expected a ")" 
unrecognized token 
expected a ";"
```

They are marked on the code. What do these errors mean?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Isn't this xmacros?

Comment: i put my questions on the top

Comment: @alk No, this is clearly F-macros, totally different :)

Comment: What happens when you compile this code in a C++ compiler? What's the problem or error?

Answer (score 4):

When you want to see what is the result after the processing just ask to see it, with *gcc*/*g++* the options is `-E`, if I do on your code the result is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -E d.c
# 1 "d.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 31 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "d.c"
# 13 "d.c"
enum mxt_object_type {
  T0 = 0, T1 = 1, T2 = 2, T3 = 3, T4 = 4, T5 = 5,
};
```

Of course here `F_SWITCH` is not used

> i have to make an equivalent in C++ but this code is in C

You have nothing to do, that does the same in C++

These macros are for the preprocessor, not for C or C++ by themselves who see the result I shown at the beginning

Example of compilation in C++ :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat d.cc
/*! Object types */
#define F_ENUM(x, y) x = y,
#define F_SWITCH(x, y) case x: return ( #x );

#define OB_LIST(f) \
  f(T0, 0) \
  f(T1, 1) \
  f(T2, 2) \
  f(T3, 3) \
  f(T4, 4) \
  f(T5, 5)

enum mxt_object_type {
  OB_LIST(F_ENUM)
};
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -c -pedantic -Wall d.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

How that works :

- first in the form `OB_LIST(F_ENUM)` `OB_LIST` is expanded producing `F_ENUM(T0, 0)   F_ENUM(T1, 1) F_ENUM(T2, 2) F_ENUM(T3, 3) F_ENUM(T4, 4) F_ENUM(T5, 5)`
- then each `F_ENUM` are expanded producing the final result `T0 = 0, T1 = 1, T2 = 2, T3 = 3, T4 = 4, T5 = 5,`

---

Classical use of `F_SWITCH` :

```
const char * nameIt(mxt_object_type v)
{
  switch (v) {
    OB_LIST(F_SWITCH)
  default:
    return "unknown";
  }
}
```

that produces :

```
const char * nameIt(mxt_object_type v)
{
  switch (v) {
    case T0: return ( "T0" ); case T1: return ( "T1" ); case T2: return ( "T2" ); case T3: return ( "T3" ); case T4: return ( "T4" ); case T5: return ( "T5" );
  default:
    return "unknown";
  }
}
```

the strings like `"T0"` are produced by `#x` who place *x* in a literal string after its substitution by its value

Comment: how can i do this to run my code and see the result ? where is this option -E?

Comment: @MrSpartan -E is the option for gcc/g++. Do you need I explain how the macros work ?

Comment: i can't compile this. it make me errors like, identifiers are undefined.

Comment: what identifiers ? Please give the compiler message and the source you compile. I edited my answer to show you that compile in C++

Comment: the errors are: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier 
identifier "RESERVED_T0" is undefined  , expected a ")"  , unrecognized token, expected a ";" . The code compiled is what you see

Comment: @MrSpartan there is no `RESERVED_` is the code you give in the question. What is your compiler ?

Comment: @MrSpartan after your editing the macro definition is break by the comments .

Answer (score 2):

This is known as "X macros", which is about making a list of constants of any kind and centralize maintenance of that list to a single place in the source code, to avoid code repetition. At the cost of readability.

In this case the `OB_LIST`, which is apparently a list of enum names and their corresponding values.

Normally it goes like this (hence the name "X macros"):

```
#define OB_LIST     \
/*  type  value  */ \
  X(T0,       0)    \
  X(T1,       1)    \
  X(T2,       2)    \
  X(T3,       3)    \
  X(T4,       4)    \
  X(T5,       5)    \

enum mxt_object_type {

  #define X(type, value) type = value,
    OB_LIST
  #undef X
};
```

Where `type = value,` is what I want each line in my enum declaration to look like. When the macro `OB_LIST` gets expanded, this "X macro" is then expaned for all values in the list, with the values specified.

After pre-processing you end up with:

```
enum mxt_object_type {
  T0 = 0,
  T1 = 1,
  ...
};
```

You can then write similar X macros for every piece of code repeating all these values. Think of it as a manner of loop unrolling, but done at compile-time.

---

The person why wrote your code has taken this practice/obfuscation one step further by not declaring the X macro locally, but instead centralizing them and passing the specific behavior on to the list of objects.

I wouldn't call that good practice, since you end up with a lot of weird macros in a header somewhere, taken away from any context.

Comment: I've also seen it done with the list in a separate file, which is included at each point of use. That can be simpler when you're just storing a list of items, rather than name-value pairs.

Comment: @TimRandall Yep, although spreading X macros across your whole project isn't a brilliant idea either. Better to localize them as much as possible. This will be possible if the design is otherwise sound.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum mxt_object_type {
  T0 = 0,
  T1 = 1,
  T2 = 2,
  T3 = 3,
  T4 = 4,
  T5 = 5,
};
```

Try googleing XMACROs

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you preprocess that code out to a file, you get:

```
enum mxt_object_type {
  T0 = 0, T1 = 1, T2 = 2, T3 = 3, T4 = 4, T5 = 5,
};
```

So this is a set of macros for creating an `enum` with member names `T#`.

Comment: And you don't even need the ` = 0` etc...as by default the first member is 0 and then subsequent ones get the next number in the sequence

Answer (score 0):

It’s using macro definition for defining another enumerated type.  F_ENUM is a macro define each item in enum. F_SWICH is a macro will be used in switch statement. This technique is used for avoiding duplicating code

Answer (score 0):

If you add code like this

```
const char * enum2str(enum mxt_object_type type)
{
   switch(type) {
      OB_LIST(F_SWITCH)
   }
   return "invalid";
}
```

you will get a function that translates `enum` values to strings without duplicating all enum values. This is useful for output, e.g.

```
enum mxt_object_type type = T2;
printf("type is %s\n", enum2str(type));
```

Sample code:

```
$ cat enum.c
/*! Object types */
#define F_ENUM(x, y) x = y,
#define F_SWITCH(x, y) case x: return ( #x );

#define OB_LIST(f) \
  f(T0, 0) \
  f(T1, 1) \
  f(T2, 2) \
  f(T3, 3) \
  f(T4, 4) \
  f(T5, 5)

enum mxt_object_type {
  OB_LIST(F_ENUM)
};

const char * enum2str(enum mxt_object_type type)
{
   switch(type) {
      OB_LIST(F_SWITCH)
   }
   return "invalid";
}
```

Preprocessor output:

```
$ gcc -E enum.c
# 1 "enum.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "enum.c"
# 13 "enum.c"
enum mxt_object_type {
  T0 = 0, T1 = 1, T2 = 2, T3 = 3, T4 = 4, T5 = 5,
};

const char * enum2str(enum mxt_object_type type)
{
   switch(type) {
  case T0: return ( "T0" ); case T1: return ( "T1" ); case T2: return ( "T2" ); case T3: return ( "T3" ); case T4: return ( "T4" ); case T5: return ( "T5" );
   }
   return "invalid";
}
```